# How to cleanly end the program with an exit code?

Tags: rust

Is there a way of returning an exit code in Rust 1.0?

I've tried `env::set_exit_status(exit_code);` but this generates a compiler error.

There is also this question: [Exit Rust program early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569718/exit-rust-program-early) which is similar but asks about the case when the process has to be exited early.

---

*EDIT: I'm looking for a solution that will also allow the process to tidy up the stack, call destructors, etc.*

Comment: @static_rtti Can you explain further what part of [Levans' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30285110/155423) is unsuitable? *Surely a systems programming language ...* remember, that Rust is also to be used in environments where there is no launcher process (like a kernel).

Comment: I hadn't read it well enough, it sounds like what I want.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Building over the comments of [@FrancisGagné 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281267/155423), if you are searching for an equivalent of C's `return exit_code`, you can artificially build it this way:

```
fn main() {
    let exit_code = real_main();
    std::process::exit(exit_code);
}

fn real_main() -> i32 {
    // the real program here
}
```

This way, all the objects of your program will be in the scope of the `real_main()` function, and you can safely use `return exit_code;` in `main` while still having all destructors properly run.

Answer (score 39):

Starting with Rust 1.26, `main` can return any type that implements the [`Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/trait.Termination.html) trait. The standard library provides implementations on several types, such as `Result<(), E>` for any type `E: Debug`. Furthermore, the trait was stabilized in 1.61, allowing third-party crates to implement it for their own types.

For `Result` values, an `Ok` value maps to [`ExitCode::SUCCESS`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/std/process/struct.ExitCode.html#associatedconstant.SUCCESS) (usually 0) and an `Err` value maps to [`ExitCode::FAILURE`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/std/process/struct.ExitCode.html#associatedconstant.FAILURE) (usually 1). The error value is also automatically printed to the standard error stream.

If you need to return a specific numeric value, use [`ExitCode`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/std/process/struct.ExitCode.html) as the return type for `main`.

```
use std::process::ExitCode;

fn main() -> ExitCode {
    ExitCode::from(101)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Rust 1.60 shows me: "`main` function is not allowed to have generic parameters
`main` cannot have generic parameters [rustc(E0131)]"

Comment: Since my StackOverflow edit time is already over, i had to add a new comment here. This is the solution for my above statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50459909/1750923

Comment: As of Rust 1.61.0, the `Termination` trait is now stable! Hurray!

https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/05/19/Rust-1.61.0.html

Answer (score 14):

[`std::process::exit`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html) exits the program with the specified exit code.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't clean up and call destructors. I'll amend the question to mention that.

Comment: Any reason why you need the clean up to happen? Do you have destructors that do "interesting" stuff? If not, then letting the operating system clean up the process is often good enough.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a direct replacement for `return exit_code;` in C. I'd like to avoid the possibility of not flushing to disk etc if at all possible.

Comment: @ThomasBratt That's exactly what you get. A return in C doesn't call any desctructors either as (standard) C doesn't have destructors.